# Photo Viewer that allows me to mark photos for further review

Tags: windows, photography, image-viewer

I took a lot a photos and want to pick the best one. To do that I would like a free software that runs on Windows 10 that shows me an image and allows me to mark the image for further review via a hotkey and that has another hotkey to switch to the next key.
After I went through all the pictures I want to easily browse those images that I marked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/) for this. Give the image a rating using the shortcuts <kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>5</kbd> and once you are finished show images only with that rating.